# Can't manage to check if a Ruby Hash contains a value

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a ruby hash which looks like

```
{"10.1.1.6"=>"nick", "127.0.0.1"=>"nick1"}
```

But I can't manage to check if a certain string is already in the Hash. I tried `has_value?`, getting array of values using `values` then using `include?` to check if it contains it, but always returns `false`, when I know that it exists. For example, I try to add `"172.16.10.252"=>"nick"` to the hash and I do:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize(*args)
    super(*args)
    @nicks = Hash.new
  end

  def serve(io)
    loop do
      line = io.readline
      ip = io.peeraddr[3]
      begin
        if  /NICK (.*)/ =~ line
          nick = $1
          if @nicks.has_value?(nick) # it fails here
            puts "New nick #{$1}"
            @nicks[ip] = nick.gsub("\r", "")
            io.puts "Your new nick is #{nick}"
          else
            message = {:ERROR => "100", :INFO=>"#{nick}"}.to_json
            io.puts message
          end
        end
      rescue Exception => e
        puts "Exception! #{e}-#{e.backtrace}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

On `irb` it works fine, but on my script it doesn't

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > h = {"10.1.1.6"=>"nick", "127.0.0.1"=>"nick1"}
 => {"10.1.1.6"=>"nick", "127.0.0.1"=>"nick1"} 
1.9.3p125 :002 > h.has_value?('nick')
 => true 
1.9.3p125 :003 > if h.has_value?('nick')
1.9.3p125 :004?>   puts "yes"
1.9.3p125 :005?>   else
1.9.3p125 :006 >     puts "no"
1.9.3p125 :007?>   end
yes
 => nil 
1.9.3p125 :008 >
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: put the entire controller code because a lot of stuff is unclear. it's unclear what is `@nicks`,`nick` and `ip` and where do you define them. thanks

Comment: done, added the relevant code

Comment: and what's the input you're entering here? is the regex working correctly? I wouldn't say there's a problem with hash. inspect the `nick` value just before the if and see what happens

Comment: That's it! I should use `$1.gsub("\r", "")` when I captured it on the regex instead of when adding it to the Hash :D If you want you can post the answer and I'll mark as correct ;)

Comment: where are you putting anything in that hash for the first time, anyways?

Comment: here `@nicks[ip] = nick.gsub("\r", "")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check how your regex is working, I wouldn't say anything is wrong with a hash.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're using "$1" the way you intend to.

In your code at this line:

```
if  /NICK (.*)/ =~ line
  nick = $1
  if @nicks.has_value?(nick) # it fails here
        puts "New nick #{$1}"
```

if line is "NICK says a bunch of things", $1 will be "says a bunch of things". So you're not really looking for the value 'nick' in your hash, but for 'says a bunch of things'.